# Magento 2.3.2 EE Composer Install Could Not Resolve

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I am using Magento version 2.3.2 EE. I am trying to run the "composer install" step (I have not modified the composer.json file in any way) and I'm seeing the following error:

```
$ composer install
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

Problem 1

```
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.2 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.2].
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.2-p1 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.3.2 <2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.2, 2.3.2-p2].
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2 requires magento/module-checkout-address-search 100.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-checkout-address-search[100.3.0].
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2-p2 requires magento/module-checkout-address-search 100.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-checkout-address-search[100.3.0].

- Conclusion: don't install magento/module-checkout-address-search 100.3.0
- Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.3.2 <2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.3.2, 2.3.2-p1].
```

Has anyone else encountered this?